# Where to start if I want to create a custom combo with popup tree viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

The normal SWT combo can only show a popup list when you click the triangle button. For some reason, I want to orgnize the selectable items in tree instead of list. It turns out I've to customize the combo to realize this. Can anyone tell me where should I begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [project Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/). It is a collection of more advanced SWT components. It does not have a tree combo, but it does have a table combo. Perhaps it will fit your needs. Even if it doesn't, you can read the source and get a good idea on how to implement it, perhaps use it as a starting point.

You can find more SWT custom widgets floating around (GIYF).

Comment: Thank you very much and I finally get this: http://tom-eclipse-dev.blogspot.com/2008/08/writing-ctreecombo-widget.html (Blocked by some countries such as PRC)